# Getting values out of a nested array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I am working on question for the Odin project.  I have to run tests on the answers I give, and am not able to pass a test by using the code I have made.  I got an unexpected result of the correct hash, but it is enclosed inside of an array for some reason.

```
def find_favorite(array_of_hash_objects)
  # take an array_of_hash_objects and return the hash which has the key/value
  # pair :is_my_favorite? => true. If no hash returns the value true to the key
  # :is_my_favorite? it should return nil
 
  
  # array_of_hash_objects will look something like this: # [
  #   { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
  #   { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  #   { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
  # ]

  # TIP: there will only be a maximum of one hash in the array that will
  # return true to the :is_my_favorite? key
end
```

My solution:

```
array_of_hash_objects.select {|key, value| key[:is_my_favorite?] == true}
```

I received this after running test:

`Failure/Error: expect(find_favorite(array)).to eq(expected_output)

```
   expected: {:is_my_favorite?=>true, :name=>"Ruby"}
        got: [{:is_my_favorite?=>true, :name=>"Ruby"}]`
```

My question is, how do I get the returned value out of an array?  I predict I might be using the wrong method, but I think it might help to get an explanation from someone who sees the problem.  No googling is solving this.  This is my first stack overflow question.

Comment: A few other notes: 1) `array_of_hash_objects.select` (or `find` as recommended in the answer) only yields a single argument (the Hash) so the block arguments should be changed to  `|h|` (right now "key" is the Hash and "value" is always `nil`) 2. `h[:is_my_favorite?]` is already a boolean (TrueClass/FalseClass) so there is no need to compare it to true. meaning the block becomes `{ |h| h[:is_my_favorite?]}`

Comment: That is a great point!  I shortened it to key[:is_my_favorite?]  == true but didn't realize that it could go even shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change from `select` to `find`. simply, the semantic of the methods is different:

- `select` returns all the elements that match the condition, so a collection, even if it's of length one or zero
- `find` returns the first element which match the condition or `nil` if none matches

in your case, you want `find`